# How to request only part of the information sent with a NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, httpwebrequest, nsurlrequest

Let's say that I need to get a NSURLRequest that will return a HTML page.But I need to read only part of the information, because the page is too huge: about 55 KB and I am doing it in the main thread (my bad, I should have done this in another thread, but now it's too complicated, I should rewrite too many lines), so it makes the views responses very slow.
The point is that I need only a small part of the page, composed by few bytes.So I would like to receive just the part of the HTML page included in some tag.How do I do this with a NSURLRequest?

Answer (score 2):

You could make a HEAD request of te information you need is in the response headers. If you need a fragment of the body then I think you are out of luck.

In either case you will probably still need to get that request off the main thread. Downloading less data is not going to reduce the latency of your connection and this request will continue to block the UI thread. Mobile connection round trip times can be seconds long and you can't control that.

---

Edit: as an example, I'm posting this answer from a device which is averaging 369kbps down but with an 1124ms latency. Every time an app makes a synchro is request on the main thread I'm going to watch the UI freeze for over a second no matter what you do to try to optimize the downloaded data.

Comment: I tried to make it in another thread, the views are still not so responsive, could you see the code where I load the request?